# How to extract and infer type arguments in a function typescript function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```
type Input = { type: 'a'; data: 'x' | 'y' } | { type: 'b'; data: 'y' | 'z' }

type DataType<T extends Input['type']> = Extract<Input, { type: T }>['data']

export const f = <T extends Input['type']>(
  type: T,
  data: DataType<T>
): Input => ({ type, data })
```

The code will fail in typescript with something like

```
    Type '{ type: "a" | "b"; data: "x" | "y" | "z"; }' is not assignable to type 'Input'.
  Type '{ type: "a" | "b"; data: "x" | "y" | "z"; }' is not assignable to type '{ type: "b"; data: "y" | "z"; }'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type '"a" | "b"' is not assignable to type '"b"'.
        Type '"a"' is not assignable to type '"b"'
```

Any ideas on how to lock down `type` to make it work?

Comment: I think that's not possible in typescript (at least now); but your type definition for `f` is safe when used from outside, so you can add a downcast to `Input` (`=> ({ type, data }) as Input`) and it will not break type safety

Comment: Good point -  that works and keeps the type safety, the same goes for removing the return type (`: Input`), well, well

Comment: I mean, there is a type safety problem, if you call `f(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b", "z");` the compiler doesn't care and yet the output has a 50% chance of not being a valid `Input`.  That can be fixed but there's still the underlying of the compiler not being able to see the correlation between `type` and `data` inside the implementation.  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NVK5Bm).  If you want that to be an answer, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Going a somewhat longer way can solve your problem.

```js
interface InputTypeMapping {
    a: 'x' | 'y';
    b: 'y' | 'z';
}

type Input = { type: keyof InputTypeMapping, data: InputTypeMapping[keyof InputTypeMapping] };
type DataType<T extends keyof InputTypeMapping> = InputTypeMapping[T];

export const f = <T extends keyof InputTypeMapping>(
  type: T,
  data: DataType<T>
): Input => ({ type, data });
```